# App-Link / Deep link only works one time on samsung or M+ Devices

Tags: android, deep-linking, samsung-mobile, deeplink

I have explored recently that Samsung devices if you integrate deep links in your app (i.e. coming from the web to in-app) the chooser dialogue open only one time after its install and after that whenever the web detects that URL deep link initialize whichever app user has chosen last time to browse that webpage. I thought before that the OS saves the user preference on that specific deep link url maybe so by deleting / re-installing app will re-initialize the 'open with' dialogue. but on some devices even after uninstalling and re-installing the app doesn't even work.

problem is sometimes it opens up the webpage without even asking for open with dialogue. I'm mostly sanity testing these deep links on Samsung devices but I think this problem could be on other devices as well. anyone else encountered this problem? is there any solution for testing purpose? Can anyone suggest something?

[image: This Deep-links 'Open With' dialogue]

Comment: can you post your manifest file code, I think issue is in your manifest file

Comment: @AbdulAziz : i dont think this problem is related to manifest. menefest only defines whether deeplink will be triggered based on a path-pattren. but rather problem is action picker prefrence which is user selected app that should be selected as default for that kind of link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so anyone having the same problem with Samsung specific devices is that Samsung devices select default apps automatically. you can change that in settings page then search for default apps and there is section **Default app selction** 
it would be "set default apps automatically" change it to "ask before setting default apps. that would solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I know that android OS asks the user to define open the url **just one time** with the app or use it as a **default application**.
You can clear default application from setting and see the choose dialog again.

Remember if you use **BROWSABLE** in your manifest, it causes your app be recognized as web application that can open urls and show your app in the web application dialogs.