# Choose application for deep linking every time

Tags: android, deeplink

I have done deep link for my Android applications. I have two applications to open? if the user tap to deep link on web-site. When the user tap to link at first time - android provides a choise between my applications. But next taps to the link start the apllication with out providing any choise.

How to provide a choise between my apps every time when user tap my deep link?

Comment: Are you sure the user didn't press to always open it using one of the apps?

Comment: Yes, there are no any checkbox to always open choosen app. May be any settings in android?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905496/app-link-deep-link-only-works-one-time-on-samsung-or-m-devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App-Link / Deep link only works one time on samsung or M+ Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905496/app-link-deep-link-only-works-one-time-on-samsung-or-m-devices)

Comment: Gustavo! That's it!!! Thanks a lot!